# sql server 2005 connection open error - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, sqlexception

I am getting following error when trying to open a connection to SQL Server 2005. I am using .Net `SqlConnection` class and the error is thrown when `open()` is called. My code runs properly from local machine but throws error from the our test server. The test server is running IIS 6.0.

Error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)
>
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>   at Portal.Data.SqlDataAccess..ctor(String ConString) in...

The connection string I am using is

```
Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=dbname;Data Source=servername;Packet Size=4096" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [website](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) that explains connection strings, it is a life saver.  But with the "Integrated Security=SSPI" it is trying to connect to the server as the user that is running the binary.  If the user doesn't have permissions to db, then boom.  9 times out of 10 that is it.

Comment: thanks. I checked the permission and the user has permission to the db.

Comment: Is the database and the test server, the same machine?  Do you have SSMS on the test machine to test connection?  It could be windows firewall or antivirus stopping the connection.  And from the test machine you are able to ping the db machine?

Comment: the database and IIS (test server) are on different machines. I don't have SSMS on the test server. I am able to ping from the test server to the database server. I tried to create a dsn from the test server and it failed.

Comment: from test server attempt to log into db server using username/password as the app is using.  And provide the error that is displayed

Comment: do you mean remote desktop into db server?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I recently encountered the same error message when connecting from an old computer to a new server. It happened while trying to make the connection, and returns error message:

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]TCP Provider: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

with SQL Server Error: `10054`. In the Windows System log on the server I found an error (Source = `Schannel`):

> An TLS 1.0 connection request was received from a remote client
>   application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client
>   application are supported by the server. The TLS connection request
>   has failed.

Basically we dropped the older TLS protocols when we upgraded the server, but the older computers didn't have the more modern protocols. It's a Windows version limitation.

In any case, for other others who have the similar problems, first check your firewall logs, then your SQL Server logs, which also include Windows logs in SSMS (under the Management tree). (The logs on the server, not the client.)